# Excel formula: Add entries in same month and year

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

This seems like it should have a fairly simple solution, but I can't quite find it. Any help would be much appreciated.

I'm trying to write a formula in Excel that will refer to an itemized list of income and expenses and add up all of the entries in a given month and a given category. So if I have the following entries in one sheet:

`6/15/16  Electric    -$80.00   Utilities
7/1/16   Landlord   -$800.00   Rent
7/2/16   McDonald's   -$5.00   Fast Food
7/15/16  Electric    -$80.00   Utilities
7/19/16  Water       -$55.00   Utilities`

I want a formula that will select and add, for example, all of the utilities from July but not from June.

Currently, I can select for category but I can't figure out how to select for the month. Here's what I'm working with:

`=SUMIFS(Spending!C:C,Spending!D:D,"=Utilities",Spending!A:A,"=MONTH(D1)&YEAR(D1)")`

The `Spending` sheet is organized just like my above example, the `C` column refers to expenses, the `D` column to categories, and the `A` column to dates. `D1` in the last test refers to the column heading, which names this column as having to do with July 2016 expenses.

*One further question, too:* I'd prefer to avoid hard-coding the second test, and instead make it refer to the row heading. So instead of saying `"=Utilities"`, say `"=A3"`--i.e., the text value of the row header. But that way of writing it breaks the formula, and I can't figure out what else to try.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bracket the dates with greater than and less than:

```
=SUMIFS(Spending!C:C,Spending!D:D,C1,Spending!A:A,">=" & DATE(YEAR(D1),MONTH(D1),1),Spending!A:A,"<=" & EOMONTH(D1,0))
```

[image]

---

For reference Spending sheet:

[image]

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks so much. That works like a charm. Any guidance on the second part of the question---how to avoid hard-coding the category reference?

Comment: @BrianHamilton sorry missed that part, just put the value in a cell and reference that.  See edit.